# HTML Custom Elements creation fails on Safari, custom method is not known

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I create a custom button in my HTML JavaScript. While it works on Chrome like intended, it fails on Safari. Neither will the constructor be called, nor can I call the method "MyMethod" by my own. What do I miss?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Button Element Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button is="myown-element-button">Click me!</button>

    <script>
      // Define the custom button element
      class MyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.addEventListener("click", this.myMethod);
        }

        myMethod() {
          console.log("Hello from MyButton!");
        }
      }
      customElements.define("myown-element-button", MyButton, { extends: "button" });

      // Create a new custom button element
      const myButton = document.createElement("button");
      myButton.setAttribute("is", "myown-element-button");

      myButton.textContent = "Click me too!";
      document.body.appendChild(myButton);
      myButton.myMethod();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**
In the code example before I used

`const myButton = document.createElement("button", { is: "myown-element-button" });`
Which does not work in Safari. I resolved that by using:
`myButton.setAttribute("is", "myown-element-button");`

Now it works neither in Chrome and Safari :(

If I remove the createElement part totally and get my button from the html to call myMethod, it also fails in Safari and works in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue but the attribute `is` is not supported by Safari, see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/is)

Comment: @JSONDerulo Yes, I will correct that bug, but the basic problem is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Safari does not support customising built-in elements.

Here the current state:
https://caniuse.com/?search=Custom%20elements

And here a threat showing that there is no plan from the Safari team to implement customising built-in elements:

https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/97

As I am not planning to use polyfill, I have to throw away several days of work done in Chrome.